# How to get the particular index from the table stored in a file

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures, line-processing

I am taking the output from  a file in tabular form.

This is how the file.txt will look like. suppose its a 4*4 matrix

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
```

Now i want to fetch a particular element of the table say 2nd row and 3rd column. I am using the below code but i am not getting the ouput.

I am storing the table in a array and taking the ref of it.

```
open(FH, "file.txt);
@Table = <FH>;
close FH;
$ref = \@Table;
print "${$ref[2][3]}";
```

The ouput should be "c"

Please tell me why ouput is not coming

Comment: Could you provide example input and the desired output and more of your code, please? People may be able to help you if it is more clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey i modified the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that works as you want:

```
# ALWAYS use these 2 lines at the begining of your programs
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'file.txt';
# use lexical file handler, 3 arg open and test if open is OK
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading:$!";
my @Table;
while(<$fh>) {
    push @Table,[split];
}
close $fh;
my $ref = \@Table;
# this prints the third element of the second line
# array index start at 0
print $ref->[1][2];
```

**output:**

```
c
```

Comment: Thanks. 
can u use this also
print ${$ref}[1][2];

Comment: @Nitesh: No, you can't. Like I mentioned in my answer, you can use `print @{$ref}[2]->[3]`, but I don't know why you'd want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean to write is

```
print "$ref->[2][3]";
```

or

```
print "@$ref[2]->[3]";
```

From your description, I assume you've declared `@Table` something like this:

```
my @Table = ([1, 2, 3, 4], 
     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
     ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
     ['i', 'j' 'k' 'l']);
```

That is, I'm pretty sure you left off `my` since you aren't using `use strict;`. How do I know this? You would have gotten a message saying `Global symbol "@ref" requires explicit package name` if you had used it. What you're trying to access with `$ref[2]` is an element in the array `@ref`; not an element in the array ref `$ref`. It's also possible that you used parens (`(` and `)`) to enclose the inner arrays instead of brackets (`[` and `]`), which is a problem, because that would cause Perl to flatten the array into

```
my @Table = (1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' 'k' 'l');
```

which isn't what you want.

There are multiple problems with `${$ref[2][3]}`. First of all, the proper way to access elements within an array ref is `$ref->[2]->[3]`, which can also be written as `$ref->[2][3]` (I usually avoid that notation, since I think it's less intuitive). Had you succeeded in fetching that element, you would have wound up with `${"h"}`, which is a problem, because Perl complains that `Can't use string ("h") as a SCALAR ref`.

**EDIT:** Since the question changed quite a bit after my answer, here's an applicable solution for the record:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ref = [];

open (my $fh, "<", "file.txt") or die "Unable to open file $!\n";
push @$ref, [split] for (<$fh>);
close $fh;

print $ref->[1]->[2],"\n"; # print value at second row, third column
```

I saw this [Perl references quick-reference](http://perlmonks.org/?node=References%20quick%20reference) posted in another answer on SO the other day. You would benefit from having a look at it. And never write Perl code without `use strict;use warnings;`. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: I want to fetch 2nd row and 3rd column. say $i = 2 and $j = 3.

Comment: yes $ref->[2][3] and ${$ref[2][3]} are same.. But i am not getting the output. My doubt is that i want to get a particular element of the table(say 2nd row and 3 column). How to do it

Comment: @Nitesh: Then you have to use `$ref->[1][2]` since Perl uses zero-based indexes. No, they're not the same.

Comment: I think the below code will work

read line by line
and then store each line in an array
then make a one array like
@Table = qw/\@array1 \@array2 \@array3 \@array4/;
and then all same code as i mentioned

Comment: Whats the difference between $ref->[2][3] and ${$ref[2][3]}

Comment: @Nitesh: `$ref->[2][3]` accesses the array ref `$ref`. `${$ref[2][3]}` accesses the array `@ref` and tries to take the scalar ref at the element at that position.

Answer (score 1):

No, it *shouldn't* be 'c'. Not if you want the *3rd* row ( indexes: 0, 1, 2 ) and *4th* column (indexes: 0, 1, 2, 3 ).

Perl is a zero-index language, like C and Java and *any number other languages*. If you want `$table->[2][3]` to be 'c', you need to assign it in a certain way.

Also, simply making an array of the lines is *not* going to work. `@Table = <FH>;` just creates a single-dimensional array with the four lines in it. You would need to do *at least* this:

```
@Table = map { [ split ' ' ] } <FH>;
```

However, that's still not going to fix the index issue. But this will:

```
@Table = ( undef, map { [ undef, split ' ' ] } <FH> );
```

I *do not* recommend setting [`$[`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARRAY_BASE)!!